# loop stops without any error message renaming/moving files

Tags: python, file, rename, move

In below program I am trying to rename files present in my directory. However each time I run different number of files are renamed and program stops without any error message.

```
'''
Created on 08-Jul-2017

@author: Pranav
'''
import os
import re
from shutil import move

class MyPatterns:
    brackets = "([\(\[]).*?([\)\]])"
    extra_spaces_pattern = " +"

class MyConstants:
    #dir_path = "D:\Other\Books\Knowledge"
    space = ' '
    underscore = '_'    
    blank = ''

def resolve_filenames(dir_path,filename):
    new_file_name = re.sub(MyPatterns.brackets,MyConstants.blank,filename)
    new_file_name = re.sub(MyPatterns.extra_spaces_pattern,MyConstants.space,new_file_name)
    new_file_name = new_file_name.replace(MyConstants.underscore, MyConstants.space)
    new_file_name = new_file_name.title()
    move(os.path.join(dir_path,filename),os.path.join(dir_path, new_file_name))


base_path = "D:\Other\Books"
directories = os.listdir(base_path)
print('Starting process to resolve file names from base path : {}: '.format(base_path))
for d in directories:
    dir_path = os.path.join(base_path, d)
    print('Resolving files for directory : {} '.format(d))
    for i,fname in enumerate(os.listdir(dir_path)):
        print(i,fname)
        resolve_filenames(dir_path, fname)
```

Comment: Please include your code in your question.

Comment: Please edit your question (don't post a new comment), add a code block and put your code there. This is not readable

Comment: Done. Please help

Comment: What is `new_file_name.title()` doing?

Comment: .title is use to capitalize first letter of word